# Scale down larger external cloned screen in Windows a la macOS

Tags: display, bootcamp, resolution

On **macOS** on my MBA 2012 I can configure an external display (with a greater resolution than my internal display) to be used in its native resolution **and be cloned** to the internal display (with scaling applied to fit). This is accomplished using the only GPU present on the machine (Intel HD 4000).

When using **Windows 10** (22H2, bootcamp install) on the same machine I have Intel's graphics drivers (10.18.10.4252) installed and access to their configuration tool, but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish the same thing -- whenever I **clone** the displays I'm *unable to increase the larger display's desktop's resolution* above that of the internal display's native resolution.

##### Currently possible cloned destkop resolutions

- macOS

  - external display: 1080 x 1920
  - internal display: 1080 x 1920, scaled down to fit 1440 x 900
- Windows

  - external display: 1440 x 900, with option to scale up to fit 1080 x 1920
  - internal display: 1440 x 900

**Can I somehow get the equivalent of macOS's configuration working on Windows using, for instance, Intel's supplied tools?**

I'm currently not sure which part (the OS, or the GPU/drivers natively) is responsible for scaling down the larger desktop to fit the smaller screen in macOS. I'm asking in the hopes that it might be the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of scaling is managed by the operating system. What you see is a feature of macOS - it is not as such a feature of the GPU. I.e. the GPU does not have a "please clone external display to internal display while scaling it down"-feature - and as such there's no tool to activate such a feature directly on the GPU itself.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. By the way, how did you determine this? I started suspecting that this might be the case but wasn't sure. This also explains why there's a noticeable performance hit when scaling down a larger screen.